# php header() working in localhost but not working on live server?

Tags: php, header, location

```
if ($num_rows == 0 && $num_rows2 == 0) {
    echo 'result1';
    header('Location:enter-work.php');
    die();
} else if ($num_rows >= 0 || $num_rows2 >= 0) {
    echo 'result2';
    header('Location:similar-work.php');
    die();
}
```

I have the above code that I'm testing with and it properly echos out the sample text 'result1' or 'result2' every single time I refresh the page with this code, but it is not redirecting to enter-work.php or similar-work.php like it does on my localhost server. On my localhost server, I can even link it to online websites (ie. google.com). And I inputed the above code before any html was written - so before even the doctype was declared.

Not sure what's causing the problem, need some help.

EDIT: as Pekka mentioned in his comments (on the selected answer) the problem was I had echos and white spaces before the header() function.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What error do you get? On my localhost it works too.

Comment: I don't get any errors like 'header not defined'. It just outputs 'result1' or 'result2' and then a blank page since I used the die() function right after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mustn't output any content before sending headers.

That the local and live server behave differently if you do, may be because of different [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) settings.

Anyway, it should work if you remove the echos.

Comment: I just tried this and removed every single echo function I had prior to the header() function. There's also no other print() function before the header() functions either. It didn't work. I also tried making the doctype and the opening header tag come before my header() function but that didn't work either.

Comment: That's strange. Can you try an absolute URL? (http://...) but most browsers should accept it without

Comment: that isn't working either, could you give me a tip on what to change in the output buffering settings? I'm new to that.

Comment: @Qlidnaque try a completely empty PHP script and put the `header()` into the first line. Does that work?

Comment: yes, that does work, so I guess I'm doing something wrong with my code somewhere.

Comment: @Qlid I think you are outputting something before the header - maybe there is some whitespace somewhere?

Comment: thanks Pekka, you were right, I had some blank spaces before the header() function. I removed them and now its working as intended.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4540/discussion-between-qlidnaque-and-pekka)

Answer (score 0):

for any one still face same problem :
first try just simple `header()` code in `yourfile.php` and remove any other content if the problem solved that is mean the problem in your old code.

second : `header ()` should work even with another content like echo "" etc ...

last :if you tried simple `header()` code and the the problem still not solved contact your hosting provider.