# page is not redirecting after image upload

Tags: php

page is not redirecting after image upload,it is working without any problem in localhost.

```
<?php

    if(! empty($_FILES["img"]["name"]))
    {
        include("config.php");
        $temp=pathinfo($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
        $ext=strtolower( $temp["extension"]);
        $file_nm=time()."_chiragexport.".$ext;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"],"../uploads/".$file_nm);
        //convert  size
                include('includes/resize.php'); 
                $image = new SimpleImage();
                $image->load('../uploads/'.$file_nm);
                $image->resize(250,250);
                $image->save('../uploads/small/'.$file_nm); 
        //product code---------------------
            $code1=rand(1000,9999);
            $a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            $code=substr($a,rand(0,51),2).$code1;

        $q="insert into sub_products(sub_main_p_id,sub_p_nm,sub_p_img,sub_p_small_img,sub_p_code)
        values
        ('".$_POST['main_p_id']."', '".$_POST['sub_p_nm']."', 'uploads/".$file_nm."' ,'uploads/small/".$file_nm."','".$code."' )";
        mysql_query($q);
            header("location: sub_products.php?id=".$_POST['main_p_id']."");
        }
    else
    {
        header("location: sub_products.php?id=".$_POST['main_p_id']."");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors? Are they suppressed? `move_uploaded_file` could be erroring due to permissions, hence creating output and stopping `header()` from working. Remove any error suppression and try again

Comment: possible duplicate of [php header() working in localhost but not working on live server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908970/php-header-working-in-localhost-but-not-working-on-live-server)

Comment: i suspect the query is failing

Answer (score 0):

you are including a couple of files. Possibly one of those files has an empty line on top or at the bottom, causing the server to have sent some data already. That way, the header() doesn't work anymore

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing this very complex quotes issue try minimizing the quotes

```
    header("location: sub_products.php?id=".$_POST['main_p_id']."");
```

So use this instead of the above

```
    $val=$_POST['main_p_id'];
    header("Location:sub_products.php?id=$val");
```

Comment: This is in no way an answer to the question. This is just changing how he creates the URI string, if it was redirecting to an incorrect URL, *then* this part of the code would be worth looking into. At the moment, the OP is stating that the redirect doesn't run at all